# Linking a Button to a script on Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I'm trying to assign an image/button to a script function. Usually, in GSheets, I would right-click, and select the options, and then select a script. Is this not possible on Google Docs?

Example Image below on a GSheet. 
[image]

Comment: Not available in Google Docs.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You see the "Assign Script..." option. Click on it, and manually type-in the name of the function/script that you have in the Script Editor.

Comment: "Is this not possible on Google Docs?" I'm aware I can do it in Google Sheets, I don't get the same option on Google Docs

Comment: Not available in Google Docs as of today